# How can I log kafka messages that are not compatible to avro schema in Kafka Consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, spring-kafka

I have a requirement to log messages reaching Kafka Consumer for which there is no Avro schema compatibility.

How can I achieve this?

I suppose that by default Avro incompatible messages never reach my Kafka Consumer code. I use Spring's `@KafkaListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` - records that fail to be deserialized are sent straight to the container's error handler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do you know how I can provide an errorHandler to handle this error that ErrorHandlingDeserializer generates (e.g. for persisting to database) but without overwriting the default error handler? e.g. Which class should I extend before passing it to factory.setErrorHandler() method?

Comment: `>without overwriting the default error handler?` You can't. You must configure your own error handler with a custom recoverer (to handle the failed record). For 2.8 and later, configure a `DefaultErrorHandler` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh). For earlier versions, configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#seek-to-current); no need to extend the class, just configure it as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Confluent Schema Registry, the producer will fail to send incompatible records as the Registry will perform the compatibility checks and return exceptions to halt the producer. Those records will not reach the Consumer, correct, but not from any Spring / consumer property you've setup.

Beyond that, poison pill handling for any producer that isn't configured to use the Schema Registry (or a wrong Registry) needs to be setup through deserialization handlers. Refer properties from answer here - [How to configure Kafka consumer retry property from application.properties in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209291/how-to-configure-kafka-consumer-retry-property-from-application-properties-in-sp/70219383#70219383)